# How can I copy functions containing a specific command and delete them from the original code?

Tags: javascript

I have javascript code that contains a lot of
functions
Some of these functions contain the code 'return N('
I want an automatic way to collect and harvest all functions that contain the code 'return N('
And make a complete copy of the functions that contain the code 'return N(') and move it to another javaScript file
Then remove all functions containing 'return N(') from the original code
How can I do this in an automatic and fast way, especially since the code is large
Example:

```
function mr(J,m){return N(m- -0x3d8,J);}
function mi(J,m){return N(m- -0x192,J);}
function mL(J,m){return N(J-0x2bc,m);}
```

There are many of these functions in my code, and the code I am working on is very large. Is there an automatic way to copy these functions to another folder and delete them from the original code?
I will be grateful to anyone who helps me in this matter

I tried this code but it didn't give good results

```
// Define a regular expression to match functions that contain the code 'return N('
const regex = /function\s*\w*\s*\([^)]*\)\s*{[\s\S]*?return N\(/g;

// Define the original code as a string
const originalCode = `
  function foo() {
    // do something
    return N(value);
  }
  
  function bar() {
    // do something else
    return N(value);
  }
  
  function baz() {
    // do something else
    return otherValue;
  }
`;

// Use the regular expression to match all functions that contain the code 'return N('
const matches = originalCode.match(regex);

// If any matches were found
if (matches) {
  // Create an empty array to store the modified functions
  const modifiedFunctions = [];

  // Loop through the matches
  for (const match of matches) {
    // Use string manipulation techniques to remove the function from the original code
    const modifiedFunction = match.replace(/function\s*\w*\s*\([^)]*\)\s*{/, '').replace(/}$/, '');
    // Add the modified function to the array
    modifiedFunctions.push(modifiedFunction);
  }

  // Join the modified functions into a single string
  const modifiedCode = modifiedFunctions.join('\n');

  // Log the modified code
  console.log(modifiedCode);
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting the code to work after you've removed all these functions?

Comment: there is a similar question on Unix SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467406/how-to-move-a-line-from-a-file-to-the-other-file-on-the-basis-of-pattern-matchin

Comment: Yes, I want to copy it to another folder and delete it from the main code @Andy